# Why is the return keyword not giving me the desired result?

Tags: javascript, loops, while-loop, return, break

There is this challenge that I'd love to overcome. I've been stuck for almost 2 weeks. Here is the code:

```js
function multiply(top,bottom){
  var num = top;
  var multiple = 2;
  while (num <= bottom){
    num *= multiple;
    console.log(num);
  }
  return num;
}

console.log(multiply(5, 100));// expected outcome is 80
```

I'd love to return  the last result from the console.log which is 80 but each time I use the return keyword, it doesn't bring the desired result.

Comment: I don't know what is the desired result, but you have `console.log(num`)` and than you change the `num` variable. Move the `console.log` to the end of the `while` loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have another variable which keeps track of the next multiple, so that we can check it before we assign it to `num`.

```js
function multiply(top,bottom) {
 var num = top;
 var multiple = 2;
 var next = num * multiple;
 while(next < bottom) {
  num = next;
  next = num * multiple;
 }
 return num;
}

console.log(multiply(5, 100));
```

Comment: You mean it should be: ```while (num === bottom)```?

Comment: You mean you need the second last result from the console.log?

Comment: Yeah, sorry, I misunderstood. The desired result is the first console.log result.

Comment: @Fu91t1v3 Yep, but you're increasing the value one more time after `80` has been logged.

Comment: @Teemu, I don't know why that is happening. I'd love to stop it and 80, and also have that value returned.

Comment: @ShriHaril Thanks, I've seen that but it's not following the condition. It should return 80 not 160. Please.

Comment: Actually, it returns `80`

Comment: Just seen that, now. Thanks for your support. Love you guys.

Answer (score 0):

What's happening here is that you are multiplying a number and doing so until it reaches the desire result. But since it's not adding 1 with each step it can exceed the result.
What you need is have separate variable to store the previous value:

```js
function multiply(top,bottom){
  var num = top;
  var multiple = 2;
  while (top < bottom)
  {
    num = top; //get prevous value
    top *= multiple;
    console.log(num);
  }
  return num;
}

console.log(multiply(5, 100));// expected outcome is 80
```

Or having 1 less step is to do the calculation inside the `while` condition:

```js
function multiply(top,bottom){
  var num = top;
  var multiple = 2;
  while ((top *= multiple) < bottom)
  {
    num = top; //get prevous value
    console.log(num);
  }
  return num;
}

console.log(multiply(5, 100));// expected outcome is 80
```

Comment: Oh, that was the cause. I've spent nights on this. Thanks, once again.